# Splitting lines on UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, split

I have created a shape and inside of it different segments with `UIBezierPath`. I need to draw a line at the end of each segment o the donut would look like it's being partitioned.

How can I draw that line?

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a line or how to determine the angle to the end of a donut segment? It would also help to know how you're creating the `UIBezierPath`s for the different segments and how that relates to the outer shape.

Comment: Trying to determine the angle to the end of a donut segment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to draw line.

```
//object of UIBezierPath
let path = UIBezierPath()

//Moves the receiver’s current point to the specified location.
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200))

//Appends a straight line to the receiver’s path
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200))


//below code for draw line with use of path which is above code
let progressLine = CAShapeLayer()
progressLine.path = path.cgPath
progressLine.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
progressLine.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
progressLine.lineWidth = 10.0[![enter image description here][1]][1]
progressLine.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

// add the curve to the screen
self.view.layer.addSublayer(progressLine)
```

This look like below image
[image]

Comment: This has started to work but its drawing the internal line of the segment, which I don need. How can I get rid of it ?

Comment: How could I draw just the vertical lines ?

Comment: @JavierSanzRozalén you need to working on the "path.addline",just look in above code to vertical line I just change y axis of "path.addline".